# Mysql (innodb) index decision for better perfomence

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have a simple table with 1,000,000 rows.
this row has a datetime field that I am always quering where statement on it.

```
SELECT * from my_table WHERE date_time = 'blabla';
```

Is it reccomened to put index on it for that reason only (where statement)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, put an index on fields in the where clause.

Just take a look at the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` (put it in front of your query) and see what the query actually touches.

Also note: Do not use SELECT *, but always the fields you actually use

Answer (score 1):

Definitely yes.  Without it, MySQL will have to do a full table scan (go row by row comparing the date_time to the provided value.)